# Permuations and Combinations problem

Tags: permutations

A football team consists of 3 players who play in a defence position, 3 players who play in a midfield position and 5 players who play in a forward position.Three players are chosen to collect a gold medal for the team.Find in how many ways this can be done if the captain,who is a midfield player,must be included,together with one defence and one forward player.

My attempted answer: 4C1*3C1
is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose the captian so its only a way to choose the captain, for the defence you have 3 players so you have 3 choices and for the forward players you have 5 choices so the number of choices is : $1$x$5$x$3$=$15$ way or choice

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
So, we have to pick the captain, one defence player, and one forwarder player. In how many ways can you pick one of each, and what will we get when we multiply that together?
(And why do we multiply those three factors together?)

Comment: @MonkeyKing Ooops, I've edited the answer. Thank you.